# Creating multiple choice question and allowing 2 or more choices in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, survey

By reference to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ it is possible to create multiple choice question with one choice allowance with this code:

```
        <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
        First radio
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
        Second radio
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
        Third radio
      </label>
    </div>
```

But I need to create multiple choice questions with 2 or possibly more choice allowances. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the name on the input tags so the 2 questions would be separately selected on the radio buttons.

```
<h5>Question 1:</h5>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Form1" id="form1Option1" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="form1Option1">
    First answer
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Form1" id="form1Option2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="form1Option2">
    Second answer
  </label>
</div>

<h5>Question 2:</h5>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Form2" id="form2Option1" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Option1">
    First answer
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Form2" id="form2Option2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Option2">
    Second answer
  </label>
</div>
```